# Which airport in Jakarta does the flight land from Bintan Island? Is it CGK airport?

Tags: air-travel, jakarta, cgk

I am taking a flight from Bintan Island to Jakarta and departing from Jakarta airport to Taipei on the same day. Does the flight from Bintan island land in CGK and the flight from Jakarta to Taipei also depart from CGK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tanjung Pinang to Jakarta flights land at CGK. You don't mention the airline you're flying with, so it's guesswork, but most probably your flight from CGK to TPE will be at CGK too.

Comment: +1, last I checked there are no international flights at all from HLP.